# Is it safe to use the read lock of sync.RWMutex for writing and its write lock for reading if the writes never race with each other by design?

Tags: go, concurrency

From the Go docs:

> A RWMutex is a reader/writer mutual exclusion lock. The lock can be
>   held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single writer.

This introductory sentence is never followed by a definition of what a reader and writer may and may not do. Thus, I wonder whether a certain stretch of the definition is possible.

Suppose we have a set of many goroutines; let's call it `S`. Each of the goroutines in `S` has its own resources which it reads from and writes to frequently. Suppose I have one extra goroutine `R` which routinely wants to scrape the state of the resources written by the goroutines in `S`. Let's explore the two more obvious solutions to see where I am going.

1. We can use a single mutex. However, the goroutines in `S` would needlessly compete for the lock, since each goroutine from `S` accesses only its own resources anyway.
2. Use one mutex for each goroutine in `S`. This eliminates needless competition and even gives `R` the option to decide whether it needs to have locked all mutexex at once or merely each mutex at least once at some point in time. Requires some extra work however.

So my third idea is this: Let the goroutines in `S` take the read lock of a `sync.RWMutex` when they want to read or write (i.e. a generalized *inclusive lock*) and let `R` take the write lock of that mutex when it wants to read (i.e. a generalized *exclusive lock*). In other words:

**Is it safe to use the read lock of `sync.RWMutex` for writing and its write lock for reading if the writes never race with each other by design?**

Comment: Yes. What the "readers" and "writers" do does not matter. They typically read and write some shared data and concurrent reads do not lead to races. But basically it is just "arbitrary number of Rs or one single W". All you have to make sure that the Rs do nothing racy.

Comment: So... `RWMutex` is a misnomer?

Comment: No. concurrent reads never race an concurrent writes always race and this is the standard use case for RWMutex. Also it is RWMutex not ReadWriteMutex :-)

Comment: RWMutex is a pragmatic name for the common use case. I wouldn't call it a misnomer. You can use a phone as a paper weight, but that doesn't mean that all phones should be called paper weights.

Comment: Imho my case is more analogous to calling a phone a computer (rather than a paper weight), but I understand your sentiment.

Comment: If you want to think of it at a more abstract level, a mutex protects a shared resource of some kind. What defines "readers" is that they never interfere with each other when they use the resource. What defines a "writer" is that its use of the resource potentially interferes with every other user.

Comment: The mutex itself isn't safe or unsafe for anything. Code with no mutex can be safe; code with a mutex can be unsafe. The mutex doesn't care what the code that uses it actually does, it's just a lock. It's the code that's using it that's safe or not, and that code isn't shown here.

Comment: The word "safe" refers to being proof against data races in this context. I believe everything else that is needed to understand the full extent of the question is contained within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of your question is Yes, just like Volker said.

I would give you a more idiomatic Go solution:

```
every resources of goroutines in S take a sync.RWMutex
the goroutines in S read after sync.RWMutex.Rlock()
the goroutines in S write after sync.RWMutex.Lock()
extra goroutine R read after sync.RWMutex.Rlock()
```

I think you just go into the wrong region, it should be a simple problem. :)

If I misunderstand you, tell me.

Comment: Your solution means a mutex per goroutine/resource. OP's option 2.

Comment: Fine. I would say it's best to choose option 2 if so.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself because of all the confusion.

Yes, it is safe to use the read lock of `sync.RWMutex` for writing and its write lock for reading if the writes never race with each other.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    m := &sync.RWMutex{}
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    maxWriters := 5
    wg.Add(maxWriters+1)
    allData := make([]uint64, maxWriters)
    go showAccumulatedData(m, wg, allData)
    for i := 0; i < maxWriters; i++ {
        go writeData(m, wg, &allData[i])
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(accumulateData(m, allData))
}

func writeData(m *sync.RWMutex, wg *sync.WaitGroup, d *uint64) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        m.RLock()
        *d++ // Write during read-lock.
        m.RUnlock()
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func showAccumulatedData(m *sync.RWMutex, wg *sync.WaitGroup, allData []uint64) {
    for i := 0; i < 15; i++ {
        fmt.Println(accumulateData(m, allData))
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*50)
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func accumulateData(m *sync.RWMutex, allData []uint64) uint64 {
    var accumulator uint64
    m.Lock()
    for _, v := range allData {
        accumulator += v // Read during write-lock.
    }
    m.Unlock()
    return  accumulator
}
```